# How to move picture in android

Tags: android, image, layout

I want to make an Application that show a picture, and we can move that picture with some button an the side of picture. let's say this the layout of my Application. 
[image: Top of Picture]

when we click the "TOP" button, it will show top side of the picture.

[image: Middle of Picture]

so, when we click "CENTER" button, it will show middle side of the picture.

[image: Buttom Of Picture]

when we cliok "BUTTOM" button, it will show button side of the picture.

and when we click "UP button, it will move picture pixel by pixel to top side, and also "DOWN" button will move down the picture. but i got the problem. when i add the picture on the layout, it show all part of picture. i want my Application can show the part that we choise. can someone help me?

Comment: We can't really diagnose a coding problem without code.  What code do you have?  What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: i didn't yet do coding. because  when i drag the picture to layout designer, it show whole of the picture, and didn't yet find way to make it just show a part of the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have an imageview embedded into a scrollview.  Then, in code, you can set up button click handlers that sets the scrollview to particular positions.